# Select2 not working inside modal in bootstrap 4.6.0

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm new to bootstrap 4 and I'm already seeking for any alternative for this problem. Both of select2 working properly like normal but when I put it inside `@include()` in modal tab-content it start to work differently.

**This is when `peralatan` is placed on top of `tindakan` :**

[image]

```
<div class="tab-content p-7 pe-3" id="tab-layanan">
                   {{-- Peralatan --}}
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="peralatan" role="tabpanel">
                        @include(
                            'pasien.tindakan_peralatan._modal_tambah_peralatan'
                        )
                    </div>
                    {{-- Tindakan --}}
                    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="tindakan" role="tabpanel">
                        @include(
                            'pasien.tindakan_peralatan._modal_tambah_tindakan'
                        )
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**And this is when `peralatan` is placed under `tindakan` :**

[image]

```
            <div class="tab-content p-7 pe-3" id="tab-layanan">
                {{-- Tindakan --}}
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="tindakan" role="tabpanel">
                    @include(
                        'pasien.tindakan_peralatan._modal_tambah_tindakan'
                    )
                </div>
                {{-- Peralatan --}}
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="peralatan" role="tabpanel">
                    @include(
                        'pasien.tindakan_peralatan._modal_tambah_peralatan'
                    )
                </div>
            </div>
```

The below dropdown is not working properly when `peralatan` is placed under inside `tab-content` (the indicator is when the placeholder is not showing), I've been thinking it was the problem of `tab-content` but also it's not closed to other possibility like `modal` from bootstrap itself.

**Another JS code to process hide/show each of `div` id for both `peralatan` and `tindakan` :**

```
<script>
    if($('#tipe-data').val() === 'Peralatan'){
        $("#tab_tdk").addClass('active')
        $("#tab_alat").removeClass('active')
        $("#tindakan").addClass('show active')
        $("#peralatan").removeClass('show active')
    
    }else{
        $("#tab_tdk").removeClass('active')
        $("#tab_alat").addClass('active')
        $("#tindakan").removeClass('show active')
        $("#peralatan").addClass('show active')
    }   
</script>
```

**And here the example of select2 inside `@include('pasien.tindakan_peralatan._modal_tambah_peralatan')` :**

```
    $(document).each(function(){
            $('#input-search-peralatan-pasien').select2({
                placeholder: 'Cari Peralatan',
                dropdownParent:  $('#input-search-peralatan-pasien').parent('#modal_tambah_tdk_alat_pasien'),,
                ajax: {
                        ...}
                 ...
}
```

**Complete code of modal to showing the process:**

```js
      if($('#tipe-data').val() === 'Peralatan'){
            $("#tab_tdk").addClass('active')
            $("#tab_alat").removeClass('active')
            $("#tindakan").addClass('show active')
            $("#peralatan").removeClass('show active')
        
        }else{
            $("#tab_tdk").removeClass('active')
            $("#tab_alat").addClass('active')
            $("#tindakan").removeClass('show active')
            $("#peralatan").addClass('show active')
        }
```

```html
<div class="modal fade"  style="overflow:hidden;" id="modal_tambah_tdk_alat_pasien" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">{{__('Tambah Data Tindakan Medis & Peralatan')}}</h5>

                <div class="btn btn-icon btn-sm btn-active-light-primary ms-2" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span class="fa fa-times"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body p-0">

                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">

                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-line-tabs nav-line-tabs-2x nav-stretch fs-6 border-2 px-7 pt-3">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link active" id="tab_tdk" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#tindak">{{__('Tindakan')}}</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" id="tab_alat" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#peralat">{{__('Peralatan')}}</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                        <div class="tab-content p-7 pe-3" data-focus="false" id="tab-layanan">
                            {{-- Tindakan --}}
                            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="tindak" role="tab-1">
                                @include(
                                    'pasien.tindakan_peralatan._modal_tambah_tindakan'
                                )
                            </div>

                            {{-- Peralatan --}}
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" data-focus="false" id="peralat" role="tab-2">
                                @include(
                                    'pasien.tindakan_peralatan._modal_tambah_peralatan'
                                )
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer bg-light">
                <div class="row w-100">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-light-primary rounded-1" data-bs-dismiss="modal">{{ __('Tutup') }}</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 text-end">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary rounded-1 btn-action-simpan-tdk-alat btn-submit-tera">{{ __('Simpan') }}</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you know and can point out the problem in my code please help me to find it out, thank you :)

Comment: Hi, what is your bootstrap and select2 version ? Also, can you show html generated ?

Comment: My bootstrap version is ^4.6.0 and for jquery is ^3.6

Comment: Please create a "runnable" example with "Stack Snippets". How to create ["runnable" example.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: Hello, I'm already update my code, but I'm only can insert JS with HTML only without CSS, please look afterward

Comment: Hi, there are two select-box with same ID `input-search-peralatan-pasien` ? If yes , then **only first one with that ID will work** . Instead change that to class or use different ID's

Comment: First of all add this code on top of your snippet to at least make it work: `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Comment: In your script you check `$('#tipe-data').val()`. Where is it in your html and what's the point of this check? Is it just to change tabs?

Comment: Hello @swati each select box having one select ID input-search-peralatan-pasien and input-search-tindakan-medis-pasien, I only showing one example cause the other one is having the same structure

Comment: @1988 Can you show html generated for your both divs ?

Answer (score 1):

You should **never** change tabs like this:

```js
if ($('#tipe-data').val() === 'Peralatan') {
  $("#tab_tdk").addClass('active')
  $("#tab_alat").removeClass('active')
  $("#tindakan").addClass('show active')
  $("#peralatan").removeClass('show active')
} else {
  $("#tab_tdk").removeClass('active')
  $("#tab_alat").addClass('active')
  $("#tindakan").removeClass('show active')
  $("#peralatan").addClass('show active')
}
```

This code simply broke the tabs. If you ever need to manually interfere with tabs' state then use [proper Bootstrap functions](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/navs/#via-javascript).

---

```js
$(document).each(function(){
  $('#input-search-peralatan-pasien').select2({
    placeholder: 'Cari Peralatan',
    dropdownParent:  $('#input-search-peralatan-pasien').parent('#modal_tambah_tdk_alat_pasien'),,
    ajax: {
      ...
    }
  ...
}
```

Here you used `each()` to loop over `$(document)`. That's not what [each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) is for.

Looks like you wanted something like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#input-search-peralatan-pasien').each((input) => {
    input.select2(...);
  });
});
```

but it's also wrong. You shouldn't loop over element with id="input-search-peralatan-pasien" because you should **NEVER** have multiple elements with the same ID. Only classes can be repeated in a document, but ID must be unique.

Don't use loops, just load whatever `'pasien.tindakan_peralatan._modal_tambah_peralatan'` is supposed to load.

```js
$(function(){
  $("#modal_tambah_tdk_alat_pasien").on('show.bs.modal', () => {
    if ($('#tipe-data').val() === 'Tindakan') {
      $('#tipe-tabs button[data-target="#tindak"]').tab('show');
    } else if ($('#tipe-data').val() === 'Peralatan') {
      $('#tipe-tabs button[data-target="#peralat"]').tab('show');
    }
  });
  
  const dataTindakan = [
    {
      id: 0,
      text: 'Tindakan 1'
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      text: 'Tindakan 2'
    }
  ],
  dataPeraltan = [
    {
      id: 0,
      text: 'Peraltan 1'
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      text: 'Peraltan 2'
    }
  ];
  
  $('#input-search-tindakan-medis-pasien').select2({
    placeholder: 'Tindaken',
    data: dataTindakan
  });
  $('#input-search-peralatan-pasien').select2({
    placeholder: 'Peralatan',
    data: dataPeraltan
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css">

<div class="container py-5">
  <div class="input-group">
    <select id="tipe-data" class="custom-select">
      <option selected value="Tindakan">Tindakan</option>
      <option value="Peralatan">Peralatan</option>
    </select>
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button id="tipe-modal-button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_tambah_tdk_alat_pasien">Show modal</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="modal fade" id="modal_tambah_tdk_alat_pasien">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title">Tambah Data Tindakan Medis & Peralatan</h5>
          <div class="btn btn-icon btn-sm btn-active-light-primary ms-2" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body pt-0">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-line-tabs nav-line-tabs-2x nav-stretch fs-6 border-2 px-7 pt-3" id="tipe-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <button class="nav-link" id="tab_tdk" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#tindak">Tindakan</button>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <button class="nav-link" id="tab_alat" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#peralat">Peralatan</button>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <div class="tab-content" id="tab-layanan">
            <div class="tab-pane p-4 bg-light fade" id="tindak" role="tabpanel">
              <select id="input-search-tindakan-medis-pasien"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane p-4 bg-light fade" id="peralat" role="tabpanel">
              <select id="input-search-peralatan-pasien"></select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between bg-light">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-dark rounded" data-dismiss="modal">Tutup</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary rounded btn-action-simpan-tdk-alat btn-submit-tera">Simpan</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello sharak thank you for your answer, beforehand I'm already using $(document).ready(function(){}) and I forgot to correct it before I enter it into stackoverflow, and for the ID of input-search-peralatan-pasien, I'm actually having two ID and each of select dropdown is having their own ID, it's input-search-peralatan-pasien and input-search-tindakan-medis-pasien. I have try JS code for modal page that you suggest but it's not working well, it still showing the same result as before when dropdown inside peralatan not working when I try to open it.

Comment: @1988 you didn't provide enough information to fully fix your issue. Where's `#tipe-data`? I don't see it in your code. I added it in my snippet and it works as it should: based on the value of `#tipe-data` it activates correct tab inside modal.

Comment: @1988 I added select2 to my snippet. Since I don't have access to your api I used only some dummy data. It all works as expected. If you've done it the same way and still don't get desired result then the problem must be with your api.

Comment: Hello, the only problem that I found is actually on blade view in laravel, method @stack() and @push() seems like to be the problem why dropdown contains error when I clicked on it, the method @stack() actually not rendering the javascript code from @push(), thank you for your answer because it's related to my question, I didn't expecting it's actually from @push() and @stack()

Comment: Like I said, on bootstrap/jquery side everything works as it should if you use my approach. I'm guessing you already know where to look for a laravel fix but [here it is](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#stacks) :)